# INPUTS DATE JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola a todos tengo un input date con nombre fecha inicio que me bloquea las fechas anteriores, lo que necesito es capturar la fecha inicio y pasarla a la fecha final , bloqueándole el día a la fecha final para que este me permita solo modificar el mes y el año a la fecha final ; a continuación adjunto el código.

Campo fecha inicio

```
<label >Inicio Vigencia</label>
<input id="arr" type="date" name="inicio_vigencia" onchange="cal()" class="form-control" onkeydown="return false" >
```

Campo fecha final

```
  <label>Fin Vigencia</label>
  <input id="dep" type="date" name="fin_vigencia" onchange="cal()" class="form-control">
```

Codigo que bloquea fecha anterior

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var fecha = new Date();
        var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
        var dia = fecha.getDate();
        var _mes = fecha.getMonth(); //viene con valores de 0 al 11
        _mes = _mes + 1; //ahora lo tienes de 1 al 12
        if (_mes < 10) //ahora le agregas un 0 para el formato date
        {
            var mes = "0" + _mes;
        } else {
            var mes = _mes.toString;
        }

        var fecha_minimo = anio + '-' + mes + '-' + dia; // Nueva variable
        document.getElementById("arr").setAttribute('min', fecha_minimo);
    </script>
```

Comment: Con _Javascript_ puro no es posible ese comportamiento, solo puedes limitar la fecha máxima, pero no hay nada para que solo puedan seleccionar un día en específico. Probablemente alguna librería te lo permita o, en su defecto, tendrías que separar la fecha en campos día - mes - año, poniendo día como solo lectura.

Comment: Es que tengo que obligar al usuario que la fecha final inicie el mismo dia que la fecha inicial ya que son servicios anuales entonces por ende la fecha final debe comenzar el mismo dia de la incial lo unico que podria cambiar seria el mes y el año ya que hay una operacion que calcula los meses exactos entonces no se si podria existir una validacion o algo que le indique al usuario eso que necesito. @Triby